# How to rewrite URL in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working with MVC 3. As we all know MVC set URL as per the action method's name in the controller, but I need a slight modification.

I don't want to show my action method's name in the URL for security purpose. So if I have index method in Home controller, The URL will be like this: `www.server/home/index` but I want to show `www.server/home/test` in the browser. I can do this by using the `[ActionName]` attribute, but is there any other way?

Can I use a custom route handler for this?

Comment: What is the security purpose for hiding method names?

Comment: Depends on your needs. That will "Test" refer to? Is there more then one action per controller? You can use routing to acheive this but if the name is specific for each action (and custom), then you would have to add a route for each action which seems rather pointless to me (in which case [ActionName] sound more viable option). If "Test" is something specific that you can retreive or have a way to find out, then perhaps a Route or a extended Controller could be a solution. Let me know what are your goals and I'll help you out :)

Comment: Well for now I just need to do it for only one action method but by using a custom route handler. @ Pluc

Comment: I'm not very sure to be honest, but my teacher told me that sometimes it requires to hide a specific method name, because if any hacker knows the method name, then I believe it will be easy to break into the code, as he knows there is a particular method from which he can gain some valuable information. @ AlexC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to using [ActionName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute.aspx), you can define a custom route and direct it to whatever Controller and Action you want. For example:

```cs
routes.MapRoute("home/test", "home/test/{id}",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

will take paths like `/home/test` and `/home/test/42` and route them to the Index action of the Home controller.

You can also leave off the `{id}` portion if you don't need it. For example:

```cs
routes.MapRoute("home/test", "home/test",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

will only take `/home/test`.

This is also how I achieve lowercase URLs while maintaining uppercase controller and action names. I just hard-code all of my routes.

Comment: This would work for a small site, but would this not become a maintenance nightmare?

Comment: I will check this & show it to my teacher. If he approves, then I will let you know or if he suggest anything other than this, I will also share that. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @AlexC Possibly, but not necessarily. It depends on how many controllers and actions you have in your site and how often they change. It's actually easier to change a route than to rename a controller or action.